Validar lista de E-mails separados por punto y coma en Angular
Tengo el siguiente código en .html:
    <div fwdPreventScroll>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>
          Introduzca E-mail:
        </p>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emailValueTextbox" name="emailValue"  id="emailValue"
          placeholder="Ingrese el E-mail o lista de E-mails separados por punto y coma" class="form-control">
        <p>
          * Puede especificar más direcciones de E-mail separándolas por puntos y comas (;)
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="button-right-align">
          <div class="checkbox-left-align">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSendToMeCheckbox" name="isSendToMe" id="isSendToMe">
            <label for="isSendToMe">Enviarme una copia a mí</label>
          </div>

          <button class="btn--secondary margin-button-offset" (click)="cancel()">
            Cancelar
          </button>
          <button [disabled]="isSendDisabled()" (click)="send()">
            Enviar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

El tema es que el botón "Enviar" se debe de habilitar si el checkbox está marcado o se ha introducido un email válido:
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogRef } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { Requisition } from 'app/springter/services/services';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'fwd-requisition-send-email-modal',
  templateUrl: './fwd-requisition-send-email-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fwd-requisition-send-email-modal.component.scss']
})
export class FwdRequisitionSendEmailModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public dialogRef: DialogRef;
  @Input() public requisition: Requisition;

  public _emailValueTextbox: string;
  public _isSendToMeCheckbox: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get isSendToMeCheckbox(): boolean {
    return this._isSendToMeCheckbox;
  }

  set isSendToMeCheckbox(sendToMeCheckbox: boolean) {
    this._isSendToMeCheckbox = sendToMeCheckbox;
  }

  get emailValueTextbox(): string {
    return this._emailValueTextbox;
  }

  set emailValueTextbox(emailValueTextbox: string) {
    this._emailValueTextbox = emailValueTextbox;
  }

  public isValidEmailList(): boolean {
    var emails = this.emailValueTextbox.split(';').map(email => email.trim());
    var isValidList = true;

    for (let email of emails) {
      if (!_.isEmpty(email) && !this.isValidEmail(email)) {
        isValidList = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return isValidList;
  }

  public isValidEmail(email: string): boolean {
    var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;
    return pattern.test(email);
  }

  public isSendDisabled() {
    if (this.isSendToMeCheckbox === true || (!_.isUndefined(this.emailValueTextbox) && !_.isEmpty(this.emailValueTextbox) && !this.isValidEmailList())) {
return false;    
}
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}

El campo para E-mail puede ser de uno o varios E-mails separados por punto y coma (;). Cuando se introduce un sólo e-mail se valida correctamente. Pero si sigo introduciendo más y luego me arrepiento, al borrar el segundo e-mail introducido, y tener el primero incorrectamente puesto, el botón Enviar se queda habilitado y no debería.
¿Alguna solución?

El formato del sitio es preguntas/respuestas. Tú puedes responder a tu propia pregunta, pero aquella respuesta debe ir en la sección de respuestas y no añadirla dentro de la pregunta

Lo acabo de modificar.
Gracias por la aclaración @Yussef

Perfecto!!! Recuerda que pasado un tiempo (creo que 48hrs) puedes marcar como aceptada tu propia respuesta. Además, te aconsejo dar una pequeña explicación a tu respuesta. El sistema detecta las respuestas que son solo código y las clasifica como de baja calidad. Saludos

Hecho @Yussef, muchas gracias

Me contesto a mí mismo:
Primero hay que validar el email con la siguiente expresión regular:
public isValidEmail(email: string): boolean {
    var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/;
    return pattern.test(email);
  }

Luego hay que controlar la lista de todos los emails:
 public isValidEmailList(): boolean {
    var emails = this.emailValueTextbox.split(';').map(email => email.trim());
    var isValidList = true;

    for (let email of emails) {
      if (!_.isEmpty(email) && !this.isValidEmail(email)) {
        isValidList = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return isValidList;
  }

Y finalmente, manejar el comportamiento del botón:
  public isSendDisabled() {
    if (this.isSendToMeCheckbox === true && !_.isUndefined(this.emailValueTextbox) && !_.isEmpty(this.emailValueTextbox) && this.isValidEmailList()) {
      return false;
    } else if (this.isSendToMeCheckbox === true && (_.isUndefined(this.emailValueTextbox) || _.isEmpty(this.emailValueTextbox))) {
      return false;
    }
    else if (this.isSendToMeCheckbox === false && !_.isUndefined(this.emailValueTextbox) && !_.isEmpty(this.emailValueTextbox) && this.isValidEmailList()) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }

Es importante inicializar el checkbox, por si el usuario de primeras sólo mete emails:
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this._isSendToMeCheckbox = false;
  }


Hola, JmMoreno. Por favor explica tu respuesta para que sea de mayor utilidad para otros con tu mismo problema.

Hecho @caprilo, muchas gracias
